# Can all cardinal numbers be represented by an ordinal numbers, assuming choice?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Can all cardinal numbers be represented by ordinal numbers, assuming AC? (ZF+AC) If or if not, what would be the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. The well-ordering theorem says every set representing a cardinality is well-ordered, and thus bijective with an ordinal. You can then choose the least ordinal with cardinality $\alpha$ as the standard representative for $\alpha$.